# California State Parcel Data

Tags: shapefile, data, united-states, parcel

I am looking for California state parcel data such as owner name, no. of stories, year built etc., for each parcel. I can get to the level that I can browse them in property appraiser site but don't see data download options.

Comment: Do you have a link to the property appraiser site you are referring to?

Comment: Be prepared to spend some money.  Last time I acquired parcels for a county in CA, it was a few hundred dollars.  You *may* be able to acquire them for free or lower cost if you're working on something related to education, non-profit, or volunteer.

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, this type of data is typically created and maintained at the county level. I know of very few sources that do more than a few counties, and they're usually emergency services or government associations as Kotebiya mentions. What is available and for how much also varies widely from county to county and changes often. For example one nearby county used to give shapes with parcel ids, but no owner info - you had to pay for that. A year later it was all free. County next door you have to pay for even shapes. County next to *that* just doesn't anything available.

Answer (score 5):

I have addressed the topic in a previous question that was partially-related to this [one](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4702/958).

That being said, here are the places that I know of off the top of my head that have publicly-available parcel data in shapefile form.

Through the Southern California Association of Governments (SCAG), you can obtain parcel shapefile data for Imperial, Los Angeles, Orange, Riverside, San Bernardino, and Ventura County. In order to obtain the latest data available, navigate to this [ftp site](ftp://scag-data:$cag424@data.scag.ca.gov) and download the file titled **parcel_data.zip**.

The other one that I know of is from the San Diego Association of Governments ([SANDAG](http://rdw.sandag.org/Default.aspx)).

Comment: I found this site covering extensive dataset - https://data.sfgov.org. Don't know why there is no mentioning of this site by anyone.

Comment: I've checked that site. However, I don't see any dataset that has parcels with detailed information. The closest pieces of information relevant to this thread include "city_lots", "Parcels With Planning Department Zoning", and "Registered Businesses". I'd love to see if there was anything beyond the barest information associated with these parcels.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure the parcels of the entire state are readily available for free. You may have to look for it on a county by county basis, which may be laborious for 58 counties. 
This page has a link to the GIS site for each county: http://www.coordinatedlegal.com/gis.html

The State of California Geoportal website has downloadable parcels for selected counties: http://portal.gis.ca.gov/geoportal/catalog/search/browse/browse.page

Answer (score 1):

Following CA Counties data download information is available in the below links:

### County Name, FIPS Code ,GIS Home ,County Data Download ,Parcel Data Contact Date ,Contact Verified, Cost Information

http://ice.ucdavis.edu/doc/parcel_data_contacts

Answer (score 1):

The CA GIS Council has announced the completion of the 2014 California Parcels Dataset. It is currently available on the LA County GIS website until the State can put it on theirs. http://egis3.lacounty.gov/dataportal/2015/09/11/california-statewide-parcel-boundaries/